# Can I make a tesla coil with this setup?

Tags: transformer, high-voltage, tesla-coil

I had an old plasma globe and I ripped it apart to find a flyback transformer and some other components. I am not sure what type of circuit this is but I want to make it into a tesla coil. I wound a coil of really thin(thinner than your hair) wire around a 3/4 inch PVC pipe 700 times. I am planning to make a primary coil from standard jumper wire and will wrap it around about 30 times. Can I make a tesla coil from this? If not, what more do I need?

Comment: You can probably make one but whether you can make it work is different. If I were you I'd google how to do this and look for a hobby site where people are fond of tesla coils and might be able to provide hobby instructions.

Comment: Also, make sure of your wire insulation for the HV parts. Most standard wire is either 300V or 600V rated. The primary to secondary may exceed this, so you may need extra insulation.

Comment: I don't exactly know what to search, if you know of any guide or something somewhat followable, please help. I by no means have a complete understanding of these things.

Comment: Try Google. e.g. [Here is a link](https://www.instructables.com/How-to-build-a-Tesla-Coil/).

Comment: The tutorial does 600 turns on 1.5in. pipe and I did 700 turns on 3/4in coil. It that okay? Also, do I use the plasma globe circuit instead of the 115 VAC that the tutorial uses. Lastly, I use the output wire of the transformer as positive and the ground of the plasma globe circuit as ground of the input power supply, right? Thank you for helping.